# Can the Wordpress pagination functions be used for other objects (like WP_Users)?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Im building a page which will display a list of users based on provided criteria. My plan is the build a form and then use the submitted values to do a `get_users()` and then show the list.

I also want to be able to paginate the returned list because in some case the results might be quite long (**300+**). My experience with normal post/page pagination in **Wordpress** is that it's a bit finicky. And I have no idea how to attempt it with users.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a plugin, you can use [WordPress Users](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-users/). In case you want to do it yourself, you have to come with a more specific problem.

Comment: I'd rather not do a plugin. What additional specifics are you thinking? I'm going to have a big array of users returned by `get_users($args)`. I don't know the native Wordpress functions related to pagination well enough to guess which, if any, might be usable for this application. I guess that's basically the question. *Can* the WP pagination functions be used for other objects?